# Is the answer optional (Past Simple vs Past Continious)?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

I have the sentence.

> But she needn't have worried because on the day of the wedding (look) very nice indeed.

"Looked" shows a finished period in the past and the result has no connection with the current situation. As long as we pay our attention to the fact that the wedding was arrnged on the specific peculiar day, we should use Past Simple.

We are able to use "was looking" as well as "looked" and would be, certainly, correct when we consider exactly the moment of throwing a wedding party, though.

Comment: Can you explain what meaning you're trying to get across? It's not clear whether she (the bride?) looked nice on the day of the wedding or whether the day itself looked nice (e.g., had nice weather). You're missing a subject, in other words.

Comment: @mamster:  it is "*on* the day of the wedding" so the subject of LOOK would be "she". There is no other candidate in the given context.  Both **looked** and **was looking** would be idiomatic here, Anthony.

Comment: I don't see any question in the question. Yes, what Anthony says is correct -- if you're just looking for confirmation.